# SQL multi query get data per day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with data (Units_raw & Units_raw_andr). I want to get the units of both tables by date. I'm new to combining tables into one query, but tried the following:

```
SELECT `DateKey` AS 'date', `InstallEvents` AS 'DownloadAndroid' FROM `Units_raw_andr`
UNION 
SELECT `datetime` AS 'date', `units` AS 'DownloadiOS' FROM `Units_raw` GROUP BY 'date';
```

This gives me the following result:

```
 [ DATE ]    | [ DownloadAndroid ]
2020-04-04   |       293
2020-04-03   |       210
```

I want to achieve this:

```
 [ DATE ]    |   [ DownloadAndroid ]   |   [DownloadiOS]
2020-04-04   |          293            |        301
2020-04-03   |          210            |        202
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get this working?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  If your first query only returns those two rows, then your tables don't have the data you want.

Comment: In the second select, you need to use an aggregate function as you are using GROUP_BY clause.

And use JOIN instead of UNION, with an appropriate ON clause to get the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation that makes data sets *wider* (more columns) is called a JOIN. The operation that makes datasets *taller* (more rows) is a UNION

As such I think you want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(i.DateKey, a.DateKey) AS `Date`, a.InstallEvents AS DownloadAndroid, i.DownloadIOS
FROM 
  Units_raw_andr a
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT `datetime` AS DateKey , units AS DownloadiOS 
    FROM Units_raw
    GROUP BY `datetime`
  ) i
  ON a.DateKey = i.DateKey
```

Of course, Murphy's Law will dictate that it'll turn out you're using an old version of MySQL that doesn't support full outer join, in which case you'll need to do a left outer join union to a right outer join..

You might not be able to change it now, but try really hard NOT to use words that are reserved words in SQL, as column names. Stuff like "Date" and "DateTime" are a) reserved words and b) relatively meangingless - think of more descriptive names that say what the date is, like InstallDate, ShippingDate, PurchaseDate etc